# Creating a week generator showing Week no, 1st day of week, last day of week of given date

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create a week generator in C# for my payroll program. I have created a similar one that creates months of a year for a given date.

I would like my output as follows for a given date. E.G. Today is 4th July 2010.

If I select that I want the next 10 Weeks for the above date, I would like the following to print:

```
Week 1:   F: 04/07/2011    L: 10/07/2011
Week 2:   F: 11/07/2011    L: 17/07/2011 
Week 3:   F: 18/07/2011    L: 24/07/2011 
Week 4:   F: 25/07/2011    L: 31/07/2011 
Week 1:   F: 01/08/2011    L: 07/08/2011 
Week 2:   F: 08/08/2011    L: 14/08/2011 
Week 3:   F: 15/08/2011    L: 21/08/2011 
Week 4:   F: 22/08/2011    L: 28/08/2011 
Week 5:   F: 29/08/2011    L: 31/08/2011 
Week 1:   F: 01/09/2011    L: 07/09/2011
```

I would like the above to work for any date and for whatever number of weeks that I want to generate.

There are 4 classes:

Program.cs:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dateInfos = GetDateInfo(DateTime.Now, 6);

            foreach (var item in dateInfos)
                Console.WriteLine("W: {0} F: {1} L: {2}", item.Week.ToString(), item.FirstDayOfWeek, item.LastDayOfWeek);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static IList<DatesBag> GetDateInfo(DateTime givenDate, int numberOfWeeks)
        {
            var result = new List<DatesBag>();    
            result.Add(new DatesBag                
            { 
                Week = (WeeksOfAMonth)givenDate.Day, 
                FirstDayOfWeek = Week.GetFirstDayOfWeek(givenDate), 
                LastDayOfWeek = Week.GetLastDayOfWeek(givenDate) 
            });    
            for (int i = 1; i < numberOfWeeks; i++)
            {
                givenDate = givenDate.AddDays(7);    
                result.Add(new DatesBag { Week = (WeeksOfAMonth)givenDate.Day, FirstDayOfWeek = Week.GetFirstDayOfWeek(givenDate), LastDayOfWeek = Week.GetLastDayOfWeek(givenDate) });
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

DatesBag.cs:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class DatesBag
    {
        public WeeksOfAMonth Week { get; set; }

        public DateTime FirstDayOfWeek { get; set; }

        public DateTime LastDayOfWeek { get; set; }
    }
}
```

WeeksOfAMonth.cs:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public enum WeeksOfAMonth
    {
        Week1 = 1,
        Week2,
        Week3,
        Week4,
        Week5        
    }
}
```

Week.cs

```
namespace Payroll.Util.Helpers
{
    public static class Week
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the first day of the week.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="givenDate">The given date.</param>
        /// <returns>the first day of the week</returns>
        public static DateTime GetFirstDayOfWeek(DateTime givenDate)
        {
            return new DateTime(givenDate.Year, givenDate.Month, givenDate.Day);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the last day of week.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="givenDate">The given date.</param>
        /// <returns>the last day of the week</returns>
        public static DateTime GetLastDayOfWeek(DateTime givenDate)
        {
            return GetFirstDayOfWeek(givenDate).AddDays(7).Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

My 2 problems:

1. In program.cs, i have this line that I know is incorrect

   ```
   Week = (WeeksOfAMonth)givenDate.Day,
   ```

   How do I get to show the correct week?
2. My givenDate variable keeps adding 7 days no matter whether the month has already ended or not. i want It to skip to the next month even if the last week of the month has less than 7 days. How do I achieve this.

Any help appreciated. For those in USA, Happy Independence Day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static IList<DatesBag> GetDateInfo(DateTime givenDate, int numberOfWeeks)
{
    var result = new List<DatesBag>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWeeks; i++)
    {
        int firstWeekDay = Week.GetFirstDayOfWeek(givenDate).Day;

        DatesBag datesBag = new DatesBag
                                {
                                    Week = (WeeksOfAMonth) ((firstWeekDay / 7) + ((firstWeekDay % 7 == 0) ? 0 : 1)),
                                    FirstDayOfWeek = Week.GetFirstDayOfWeek(givenDate),
                                    LastDayOfWeek = Week.GetLastDayOfWeek(givenDate)
                                    };
        result.Add(datesBag);
        givenDate = givenDate.AddDays(datesBag.WeekLength + 1);
     }
    return result;
}


public class DatesBag
{
    public WeeksOfAMonth Week { get; set; }

    public DateTime FirstDayOfWeek { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastDayOfWeek { get; set; }

    public int WeekLength { get { return LastDayOfWeek.Day - FirstDayOfWeek.Day; } }
}


public static class Week
{
    public static DateTime GetFirstDayOfWeek(DateTime givenDate)
    {
        DateTime tmp = givenDate.Date;
        while (tmp.AddDays(-1).Month == givenDate.Month && tmp.DayOfWeek > DayOfWeek.Monday)
        {
            tmp = tmp.AddDays(-1);
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    public static DateTime GetLastDayOfWeek(DateTime givenDate)
    {
        DateTime tmp = givenDate.Date;
        while (tmp.AddDays(1).Month == givenDate.Month && tmp.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            tmp = tmp.AddDays(1);
        }
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your code takes care of the Week numbers correctly. However, It does not take care of the end's of month's correctly. For the examlpe output of 10 weeks using today's date the 5th Week od Aug and 1st Week of Sept are :Week 5:   F: 29/08/2011    L: 04/09/2011 
Week 1:   F: 05/09/2011    L: 11/09/2011

Comment: thanks again. I think I didn,t ask my question correctly. In Program.cs, if you change the code from var dateInfos = GetDateInfo(DateTime.Now, 6); to var dateInfos = GetDateInfo(DateTime.Now, 10); and then run the output, you will see that the second last line output (9th)shows Week 5: F: 29/08/2011 L: 04/09/2011 whereas it should be Week 5: F: 29/08/2011 L: 30/08/2011

Comment: Kinyanjui it gives you W: Week5 F: 2011-08-29 00:00:00 L: 2011-08-31 00:00:00. Have you copied the whole code? I've changed the Week class methods as well (GetFirstDayOfWeek and GetLastDayOfWeek).

Comment: maybe I've coded for too long today . Lol. You are right, Week number 9 is correct. How about Week number 10, i.e the last record?

Comment: I think I've overcomplicated your problem - try the solution posted by BigJump - looks like it works fine

Answer (score 2):

Not my best work, but it gets the job done.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var weekStart = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime nextWeek;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var weekEnd = weekStart.AddDays(6);
                if (weekEnd.Month != weekStart.Month)
                {
                    weekEnd = new DateTime(weekStart.Year, weekStart.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
                    nextWeek = weekEnd.AddDays(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    nextWeek = weekStart.AddDays(7);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Week {0}: F: {1} L: {2}", (weekStart.Day / 7) + 1, weekStart.ToShortDateString(), weekEnd.ToShortDateString());

                weekStart = nextWeek;
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```